# Transformar coluna com NaN e string para inteiro

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Possuo um dataframe com a seguinte coluna:

```
     Years

0    1990 
1    1990
2    1990
3    1991 
5    NaN
4    1994 
6    NaN
...  ...

Name: Years, Length: 9742, dtype: object
```

Já efetuei parte da limpeza desses dados, incluindo `np.nan` em dados faltantes.
Porém, desejo mudar o tipo de dado da coluna - visto que os dados estão no tipo `object`, desejo mudá-los para `int64` para melhor análise. É possível fazer esta mudança mesmo com `NaN` presente?

Além disso, parte dos dados estão em formato do tipo string, como `'1996'`, e não `1996` numérico, no tipo `int`.

Como prosseguir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O pandas não aceita transformar `np.NaN` em `int`, pois ele o considera um `float`. Porém ele consegue transformar em `Int64` (ou `Int16` e `Int32`). O `NaN` é transformado em `<NA>` (`pd.NA`), que é o [null para inteiros](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values), e as funções que utilizam este valor nulo, como `.isnull()` funcionam com `pd.NA` e com o `np.NaN`.

Então fazer: `df['Years'].astype('Int64')` resolve o problema dos nulos.

Mas ainda temos os `'1996'`, que não podem ser transformados em 'Int64' diretamente. Por isso, podemos transformá-los em `float` antes:

`df['Years'].astype('float').astype('Int64')`